# How to merge 3 columns into 1 whilst keeping values column separate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I have the following Pivot table:

| Subclass | Subclass2 | Layer | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | 5 |
| E | F | G | 100 |

I want to merge the 3 columns together and have Amount stay separate to form this:

| Col1 | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | NaN |
| B | NaN |
| C | 5 |
| E | NaN |
| F | NaN |
| G | 100 |

So Far I've turned it into a regular DataFrame and did this:

`df.melt(id_vars = ['SubClass', 'SubClass2'], value_name = 'CQ')`

But that didn't arrange it right at all. It messed up all the columns.

I've thought once I get the melt right, I could just change the NaN values to 0 or blanks.

**EDIT**

I need to keep Subclass & Subclass2 in the final column as they're the higher level mapping of Layer, hence why I want the output Col1 to include them before listing Layer with Amount next to it.

Thanks!

Comment: Given your example input/output... why not just `df[['Layer', 'Amount']]` ? (if you're planning on dropping the NaNs anyway?)

Comment: Ah sorry that's my mistake. I've edited the question I will not drop NaN rows, I will just change them to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
pd.concat([df,
           df[['Subclass','Subclass2']].stack().reset_index()[0].to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Layer'})
          ]
         )[['Layer','Amount']].sort_values('Layer')
```

```
    Layer   Amount
0      A    NaN
1      B    NaN
0      C    5.0
2      E    NaN
3      F    NaN
1      G    100.0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Naveed, thanks but that gives the value at the highest level. I want the Amount to be next to C and G as stated in question.

Comment: it hasn't worked I get a syntax error around the rename

Comment: @user18233539 would you mind elaborating... it's gotten a little unclear as to why it's not working as it matches what you want from your sample output?

Comment: hi John, sure. I'm using it but it's just saying:   df[['Subclass','Subclass2']]stack().reset_index()[0].to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Layer'})
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Comment: @user18233539  you're missing a period before the **stack**, copy paste the line perhaps and then try it out

Comment: ah right! Sorry that did work! Thank you so much! I will look more into stacking with pd.concat it's much more porwerful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation. Using a `stack` instead of `melt` to preserve the order.

```
out = (df
   .set_index('Amount')
   .stack().reset_index(name='Col1')
   .assign(Amount=lambda d: d['Amount'].where(d['level_1'].eq('Layer'), 0))
   .drop(columns='level_1')
 )
```

*NB. with `melt` the syntax would be `df.melt(id_vars='Amount', value_name='Col1')`, and using `variable` in place of `level_1`*

Output:

```
   Amount Col1
0       0    A
1       0    B
2       5    C
3       0    E
4       0    F
5     100    G
```